# .Net core runtimes previous versions not getting removed from program files

Tags: windows, .net-core, uninstallation, windows-server-2019

I recently upgraded Microsoft .Net Core Runtime from version 3.1.31 to 3.1.32 through [dotnet hosting bundle](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/3.1) .

The installation was successful and the old version no longer show under Programs and Features but the folder still exists inside
C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.31
C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.31\

I used dotnet-core-uninstall utility to list all those that can be uninstalled but version 3.1.31 doesn't show there as well however if I check it with dotnet --info command, the older version are there.

How can I remove these older versions as they are vulnerable.